# Problemas com startActivity error Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Meu aplicativo esta fechando inesperadamente ao fazer um evento de botão no menu superior. Quando acontece isto não esta aparecendo nada no `Logcat` estou seguindo o padrão assim:

Dentro de uma `activity` eu coloco o `método` `onOptionsItemSelected` seguinte:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.favoritar){
        if (!restaurante.isFavorito()) {
            // Adiciona aos favoritos
            adicionarAosFavoritos();
        } else {
            // Remove
            removerDosFavoritos();
        }
    }else{
        Intent comentariosActivity = new Intent(getContext(), Comentarios.class); //Aqui é onde ta ocorrendo o error.
        startActivity(comentariosActivity);
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "testando",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Na minha `classe` `java` `ComentariosActivity` faço assim:

```
package com.fomedemais.FomeDemais;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.entity.retornos.Comentarios;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@EActivity(R.layout.activity_comentarios)
public class ComentariosActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Comentarios> lstComentarios;

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
public static final String BACKSTACK = "backstack";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
 }
}
```

E em minha `activity` faço assim:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff6eb6ff"
    android:onClick="startSecondActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="DRAGÃO"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_3_material"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Se tiver algo que eu possa fazer para verificar o erro, inicialmente quero apenas fazer com que a tela apareça.

Foi cuspido na tela este erro:

> 05-18 12:15:40.123 4374-16314/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                     Process: com.fomedemais.FomeDemais, PID: 4374
>                                                     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.fomedemais.FomeDemais/com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.ComentariosActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
>                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
>                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
>                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
>                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
>                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
>                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
>                                                         at com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.fragments.FragmentCardapio.onOptionsItemSelected(FragmentCardapio.java:269)
>                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2070)
>                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2118)
>                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:295)
>                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:331)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:180)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:761)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:619)
>                                                         at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
>                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Apos a alteração do `AndroidManifest` ficando assim:

```
 <activity
      android:name="ComentariosActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

ocorreu outro erro:

> 05-18 12:21:58.557 17118-17466/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.fomedemais.FomeDemais, PID: 17118
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fomedemais.FomeDemais/com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.ComentariosActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.
>                                                          at com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.NavigationDrawerFragment.onAttach(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:73)
>                                                          at android.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1454)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:937)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1149)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1251)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2311)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5901)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>                                                          at com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.ComentariosActivity.onCreate(ComentariosActivity.java:31)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: A classe **Comentario** realmente existe? Não seria **ComentariosActivity**?

Comment: é anotei errado kkk

Comment: Mas será que era esse o problema? Resolveu?

Comment: No lugar de **getContext()** coloca **NomeDaPrimeiraActivity.this**

Comment: No meu sistema este getContext(), me retorna o contexto que no caso é a tela anterior

Comment: Porque a primeira é um fragment

Comment: Tente **getActivity()** no lugar do **getContext()** então

Comment: Tentei, deu o mesmo problema

Comment: Será que pode ser alguma coisa no entity ?

Comment: Pensei que fosse por nao ter registrado no android manifest porém eu registrei

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58917/discussion-between-renan-rodrigues-and-leonardo-dias).

Comment: @LeonardoDias atualizei minha pergunta, adicionando mais informações